# Unable to drag fast views in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Why can't I drag them at all? When I open any view, I make sure it's opened as a fast view. The problem is, all of them are docked to the same stack/bar, which is undesirable. I want to stack relevant views together by dragging them around, but I'm unable to drag them at all.

Anyone face it? The documentation says fast views can be dragged around but I can't seem to, is it just any setting of mine that doesn't allow it?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, am a little new to Juno. The way I drag the fast views in Juno is somewhat different from how I drag them in indigo. Took some time to figure that out myself anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like they dropped fast views in Juno.  But you can come close by building up a set of views you want to look like fast views into multiple tabs.  Then minimize them all and they act mostly like fast views.